# jQuery Toggle one element at time with closing/hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a Js beginner, and here's my code (the pics are not the same, but it's exactly what I want) :

```
        $('#img-expand').click(function () {
        $("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $('#img-expand_2').click(function () {
        $("#work-info_2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

Look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/1/

I would like that when I click on an image, the text associated with this one appears, and that if I click on the other image, the preceding text disappears, and that the new text associated with the clicked image appears in its place.

In fact, I would like that people can open only one text at the same time.

I hope that you will include/understand my problem, and that you will be able to help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('#img-expand').click(function () {
        var slide = $("#work-info").is(":visible");

        $(".part-body-opacity p").slideUp();
        if(!slide)
           $("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $('#img-expand_2').click(function () {
        var slide = $("#work-info_2").is(":visible");

        $(".part-body-opacity p").slideUp();
        if(!slide)
           $("#work-info_2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/5/

Comment: Thanks, really nice too ! But i would like when you click on the same picture again, the text disappears.

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vk7AE/2/)

```
$('#img-expand').click(function () {
    $('[id^="work-info"]').hide();
    $("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
});
$('#img-expand_2').click(function () {
    $('[id^="work-info"]').hide();
    $("#work-info_2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`^` [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with 
a value beginning exactly with a given string.
```

`$('[id^="work-info"]');` select all elements with `id` starting with `work-info`

updated after OP's comment

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vk7AE/4/)

```
$('#img-expand').click(function () {
    $('[id^="work-info"]').not('#work-info').hide();
    $("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
});
$('#img-expand_2').click(function () {
    $('[id^="work-info"]').not('#work-info_2').hide();
    $("#work-info_2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: Wow thanks it's absolutely what i need ! How do you do that ? I don't understand all the code.

Comment: @MaadMax check updated answer.Hope you understand now if not ask me again :)

Comment: Oops, i'm sorry but there's a little problem : when i click again on the same picture, the text is "popping" again, instead of being hidden. :/